# Building a particular function with directional derivatives but not differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am interested in building a function  $f:]0,1[^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

1. $f$ is continuous
2. $f$ has directional derivatives everywhere and in every directions
3. $\forall t\in ]0,1[$,
   $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,t)=0$$
   $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(t,t)=0$$
4. the function $g(t)=f(t,t)$ is non constant.

It is clear that this function cannot be differentiable. Is it possible to build an $f$ like this? If yes, can we build an example? If no, is there a simple argument proving it?

Thank you.

Comment: If it has directional derivatives everywhere then it has derivatives in all the directions of the axes which means all partial derivatives exist. Wouldn't that make it differentiable?

Comment: @JohnDouma, in the differentiable assumption, we also require a linear link between all the directional derivative at a given point.